# Javascript -Turn the values of the properties of the javascript objects to indexed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this javascript object:

```
{
  "recommendations": [
    {
      "thing": "spiderman",
      "weight": 1.6666666666666667,
      "last_actioned_at": "2019-05-17T23:06:54+01:00",
      "last_expires_at": "2020-06-06T01:00:00+01:00",
      "people": [
        "bob",
        "alice"
      ]
    },
    {
      "thing": "xmen",
      "weight": 1.6666666666666667,
      "last_actioned_at": "2019-05-17T23:06:54+01:00",
      "last_expires_at": "2020-06-06T01:00:00+01:00",
      "people": [
        "alice",
        "bob"
      ]
    },
    {
      "thing": "barbie",
      "weight": 1,
      "last_actioned_at": "2019-05-17T23:06:54+01:00",
      "last_expires_at": "2020-06-06T01:00:00+01:00",
      "people": [
        "alice"
      ]
    },
    {
      "thing": "avengers",
      "weight": 0.6666666666666667,
      "last_actioned_at": "2019-05-17T23:06:54+01:00",
      "last_expires_at": "2020-06-06T01:00:00+01:00",
      "people": [
        "bob"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "neighbourhood": {
    "bob": 0.6666666666666667,
    "alice": 1
  },
  "confidence": 0.002462038997842016
```

}

How can I create an indexe array called `results` whose values is the values for  all the `thing` properties.

As such:
`['spiderman','xmen','barbie','avengers']`

But if I try:

```
let results = results_.map(a => a.thing);
```

I get 
`Unhandled rejection TypeError: expecting an array, a promise or a thenable`

......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

My question is different from [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) because that requires the array to be a typed in variable so the answers given do not work for me.I have gotten the solution now so pls unmark my post so I can post the solution.

Comment: `recommendations.map(({ thing }) => thing)`

Comment: @JackBashford But it is in a variable

Comment: Just prepend with `variableName.`

Comment: @JackBashford I'm sorry I'm new to js

Comment: `variable.recommendations.map(({ thing }) => thing)`.

Comment: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @JackBashford Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined